# How to install ffmpeg for Jupyter Notebook in Mac?

Tags: ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

I used the `pip install ffmpeg` command to install ffmpeg onto my Jupyter Notebook.

However, when I try to run the animation command, I get the error:

```
MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable; trying to use class 'matplotlib.animation.PillowWriter' instead.
```

How should I remedy this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I used the command: `brew install ffmpeg`.
It worked